# Uploading a file to a specific location PHP

Tags: php

I am using the following line to upload a file with a file name taken from a MySQL query. It correctly adds the file to the images folder

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$_SESSION['loggedStudent']['studentID'].".".$file_ext);
```

However, I want to put the images in to a folder within the 'images' folder called 'profilepics'

But the following doesn't work. The image doesn't appear in the folder

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/profilepics/".$_SESSION['loggedStudent']['studentID'].".".$file_ext);
```

Is this a permission issue or is my code wrong? How can I rectify this? I'm using MacOS and running Apache on it

Comment: are you saving the images in the same directory where the script is executing ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$destFile = "/root/mysite/upload_files/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destFile );
```

Comment: should use `basename($_FILES['file']['name'])` just to be safe, (perhaps its fixed) but one could manipulate the filename with a custom request to include `../` in it, call it `../index.php` and override the site https://github.com/PortSwigger/file-upload-traverser